# Datatables plugin search specific column not working

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I try to create the individual search field with this code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>DataTables Server Side</h1>
        Seacrch specific column : <input id="column3_search" type="text"/>
        <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%; background-color: black; color: white;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Column A</th>
                <th>Column B</th>
                <th>Column C</th>
                <th>Column D</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
     <!-- DataTable Pagination-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>

</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        deferRender: true,
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
        bjQueryUI: true,
        sAjaxSource: 'load_table_data',
        columns: [
            {"data": "Column A"},
            {"data": "Column B"},
            {"data": "Column C"},
            {"data": "Column D"}
        ]
    });

    $('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.columns(1) 
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
    } );


} );
</script>
```

Which i specify the `<input id="column3_search" type="text"/>` to search field of column index 1, but when i do searching it not do any search just showing the processing for a second and done.

And when i remove the `.column()` out, and try to searching with this code.

```
   $('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.columns(1) 
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
    } );
```

It working normally by search all column in the table. So what a problem with this code and how can i fix it.

This is my table_schemas.

```
SERVERSIDE_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        "data_name": "A",
        "column_name": "Column A",
        "default": "",
        "order": 1,
        "searchable": True
    },
    {
        "data_name": "B",
        "column_name": "Column B",
        "default": "",
        "order": 2,
        "searchable": True
    },
    {
        "data_name": "C",
        "column_name": "Column C",
        "default": 0,
        "order": 3,
        "searchable": True
    },
    {
        "data_name": "D",
        "column_name": "Column D",
        "default": 0,
        "order": 4,
        "searchable": True
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only it on your datatable you should add a `filter` and then `draw` :

```js
$('#column3_search').on('keyup', function() {
  let string = $(this).val();
  table.columns(1).data().filter(function(value, index) {
    return value === string ? true : false;
  }).draw();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response, i try with your code but it still not working, and when i print the `value` variable in `table.columns(1).filter(function(value, index)` with `console.log(value)` it alway show `Array [ 1 ]`, so any idea why it be like that.

Comment: @Kaow yep forgot the `.data()` before the `.filter()` in my exemple, my bad ^^, i corrected it.

Comment: It stil not working pal, it nothing change in the table. but now i saw value of `value` variable.

Comment: I curious something, is that correct the value of string variable, it display like this `Object { 0: (1) […], context: (1) […], length: 1, selector: {…}, tables: e(), table: e(), draw: e(), page: e(), ajax: {…}, rows: e(), … }`

Comment: @Kaow yeah, i also think the string variable is wrong, try with `let string = $(this).val();`

Comment: Now this is value of `value` `Array(10) [ "b0", "b1", "b10", "b100", "b1000", "b10000", "b10001", "b10002", "b10003", "b10004" ]` and value of string is exactly what i input data, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the target and searchable property in column property.

```
columns: [
            {"data": "Column A","targets":0,"searchable":true},
            {"data": "Column B","targets":1,"searchable":true},
            {"data": "Column C","targets":2,"searchable":true},
            {"data": "Column D","targets":3,"searchable":true}
        ]  

$("#column3_search").on("input", function (e) {
           table.columns(1).search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
```